# Cosa significa "squarantare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> Prendete un gargaleone e privatelo della gargacotenna e del favone, poi **squarantatelo**.

Il "gargaleone" è un animale mitico inventato da Benni per questo romanzo, ma non capisco il significato del verbo "squarantare" in questa frase. L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: La mia prima impressione è che sia un termine inventato al pari degli altri.

Comment: Anch'io ho l'impressione che sia una parola inventata. Dato che “squartare” significa dividere in quattro parti, questo potrebbe significare dividere in quaranta.

Comment: @egreg: E anche "favone" in questo contesto potrebbe essere una parola inventata?

Comment: @Charo Direi di sì.

Comment: @DaG Perché non trasformi questo commento in una risposta? Dubito che sia possibile averne una di migliore.

Comment: Grazie, @DenisNardin: aspetterei ancora un po', in caso qualcuno riesca a identificarlo come termine dialettale o altro.